# Check user for a role

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots, roles, pycord

I am trying to check if a user has a specific role, and if they have that role they can use the command but no matter if I have the role I get the else triggered.

Code

```
@bot.slash_command(name="test", description = "testing cmd")
async def test(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    role = "1023451893575450665"
    if get(member.roles, id=role):
        await ctx.send("your application has been accepted")
    else:
         await ctx.send("your application has been denied")
```

Comment: Is `role` the role name or the role id?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the role id, use the [Member.get_role](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member.get_role) method. The role id should be left as an integer, not a string.

```py
if member.get_role(role):
    await ctx.send("your application has been accepted")
```

If you know the role name, you need to check through the `member.roles` property which is a list of `Roles`

```py
if len(member_role for member_role in member.roles if member_role.name == role]):
    await ctx.send("your application has been accepted")
```

Comment: This will work for the user I'm testing for, but I would like the command to only work for people with a specific role, like an admin role?